# Web: use user location to find closest office to change information on website

Tags: html, web, mobile, geolocation, ip-geolocation

I'm trying to build an "event calendar" site for work.

My work has offices set up across the country, so they want to implement when a user visits the site it knows their location to the closest office (they'll be using it at the offices anyway) which changes the info on the site.

The site is basically:

```
Welcome! Are you in <office location>?
```

(there will be a dropdown menu to manually select the site)

Depending on the location a event calendar will appear for that office after it.

I've tried researching various answers like geolocation for HTML and Google Maps. But they only talk about showing the location on a map element. I just want to find their coordinates and put it to the closest office to display as a text through a HTML element.

Any assistance at all?

Thank you kindly

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried any IP Geolocation API for it? Although the accuracy of IP Geolocation is not always accurate as these services default to the center of the city. You can check out [ipgeolocation.io](https://ipgeolocation.io) which provides geo-coordinates to be used programmatically. Here is a sample response when invoked on a user's browser.

```
curl 'https://api.ipgeolocation.io/ipgeo?apiKey=API_KEY'
{
"ip": "33.33.33.33",
"continent_code": "NA",
"continent_name": "North America",
"country_code2": "US",
"country_code3": "USA",
"country_name": "United States",
"country_capital": "Washington",
"state_prov": "Ohio",
"district": "Franklin County",
"city": "Columbus",
"zipcode": "43218",
"latitude": "39.9747",
"longitude": "-82.8948",
"is_eu": false,
"calling_code": "+1",
"country_tld": ".us",
"languages": "en-US,es-US,haw,fr",
"country_flag": "https://ipgeolocation.io/static/flags/us_64.png",
"isp": "DoD Network Information Center",
"connection_type": "wired",
"organization": "DoD Network Information Center",
"geoname_id": "4510575",
"currency": {
    "name": "Dollar",
    "code": "USD"
},
"time_zone": {
    "name": "America/New_York",
    "offset": "-4",
    "is_dst": true,
    "current_time": "2018-05-14 15:54:13.975-0400"
}
}
```